# Не пойму как отрабатывает скрипт

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Вот скрипт, выводит на странице три отзыва посетителей случайным образом(и рисует оценку звездочками). Файлик текстовый, формата: х|х|х|х|

```
$DB = file('/home/l//test/public_html/book.dat'); 

    $s=1;

    $result = array();

    foreach($DB as $line) {
        $start = $DB[count($DB)-$s];    
        $pieces = explode("|", $start);

        $strlen = mb_strlen($pieces[5],'UTF-8');
        if($strlen <= 550 and $pieces[11]!= "" and $pieces[10]!= "") { 

            $city = "";
            if($pieces[3]!= "" and $pieces[3]!= "--") { $city = "($pieces[3])"; }

            $html_stars = "";
            for ($x=0; $x<$pieces[10]; $x++) {
                $html_stars .= "<img src=\"images/guest_stars/star_on.png\" width=\"14\" height=\"14\">";
            }
            for ($x=0; $x<5-$pieces[10]; $x++) {
                $html_stars .= "<img src=\"images/guest_stars/star_off.png\" width=\"14\" height=\"14\">";
            }

            $result[] = <<<HERE
             <div class="item tg-populartour">
                <div class="tg-populartourcontent">
                    <div class="tg-description">
                        <p>$pieces[1]<br>$pieces[2] $city</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tg-populartourfoot">
                        <p>$pieces[5]</p>
                        $html_stars
                        <em>(общая оценка: $pieces[10])</em>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
HERE;

            #if($c > 4) { break; }
        }
        $s++;
    }   


    shuffle($result);

    $rand_keys = array_rand($result, 3);

    echo $result[$rand_keys[0]];
    echo $result[$rand_keys[1]];
    echo $result[$rand_keys[2]];
```

Условие $strlen <= 550 если уменьшить - результат пустой. Отзывы с длиной меньше этого числа есть 100%! В чем вопрос. Если хоть один $result[$rand_keys[х]] пустой, пустые все. Почему так? Это особенности работы shuffle? Или я чего то не понимаю? 
Ну пускай два отзыва выведет, один. Если остальные не прошли по условию.
Т.е. если поставить, скажем, $strlen <= 400 - всё пусто. А отзывы есть и по 100 символов.
Спасибо!

Comment: Подскажите, какая у вас версия php? Запустил ваш код) все работает, давайте разбираться

Comment: phpinfo() выдает 5.6.34-pl0-gentoo.
Добавил в строчку <p>$pieces[1]<br>$pieces[2] $city $strlen</p>
Сделал копию файла и оставил только 9 отзывов.
$strlen <= 600 - есть результат. Длины отзывов: 573/381/237.
Ставим $strlen <= 500 - результат пустой. Конечно, я учитываю случайность. Так вот хоть обнажимайся F5 - результат пустой.

Comment: Вот точно сейчас выяснил, длина 170 - отзыв такой ОДИН.
$strlen <= 200 - пусто.
Да я сразу заметил странность. Такое впечатление, что он хочет что бы $rand_keys был заполнен всеми тремя значениями.

Comment: В общем не понимаю что за мистика. Поставил  $strlen  - 600.
Это же просто издержки дизайна, ради этого и ограничение это. Ну, увеличил размер блоков. Ладно.

Comment: $pieces[11] - это разрешение Администратором на попадание отзыва в случайный выбор. Просто чекбокс и значение On, да все равно, проверка на отсутствие чего либо идет. 
$pieces[10] соответственно звезды, число(1-5). Если гость забил на оценивание, $pieces[10]="" - отметаем такой отзыв тоже.
Так вот в копии файла проставил всем и звезды, и это разрешение.